# Solrj with Solr Suggester

Tags: java, solr, solrj

What is the correct way of getting results from solrj using Solr Suggester?

This is my request:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
query.setParam("suggest", "true");
query.setParam("suggest.build", "true");
query.setParam("suggest.dictionary", "mySuggester");
query.setParam("suggest.q", "So");
QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
```

However I found it extremely difficult to get the response. The way I got the response is with this:

```
NamedList obj = (NamedList)((Map)response.getResponse().get("suggest")).get("mySuggester");
SimpleOrderedMap obj2 = (SimpleOrderedMap) obj.get("So");
List<SimpleOrderedMap> obj3 = (List<SimpleOrderedMap>) obj2.get("suggestions");
```

This seems to assume a lot about the objects I am getting from the response and will be difficult to anticipate errors.

Is there a better and cleaner way than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In new versions have a SuggesterResponse:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SuggesterResponse.html

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to get it as List, below code worked for me

```
    HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient(solrURL);
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
    query.setParam("suggest.q", "Ins");
    query.setParam("wt", "json");
    try {

        QueryResponse response = solrClient.query(query);
        System.out.println(response.getSuggesterResponse().getSuggestedTerms());
        List<String> types=response.getSuggesterResponse().getSuggestedTerms().get("infixSuggester");
        System.out.println(types);
    } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the suggestions via the `SpellCheckResponse` by doing the following

```
SpellCheckResponse spellCheckResponse=response.getSpellCheckResponse();
```

Check this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.SpellCheckResponse) for more details

Comment: I tried it, it does not work. It is not a SpellCheckResponse object. It is a suggester https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32604262 which I think is different.